# Facebook's "Like This" Feature - Time & Effort required to integrate with an existing e-commerce site?

Tags: facebook

How much time, and what basic steps, are involved in integrating the Facebook's "Like This" feature into an existing e-commerce site?

Let's say we are only interested in the feature at the product details level and have approximately 5 different product details areas.

Thanks

Edit: Pic for anti-ambiguity protection:
[image]

Comment: Facebook had an army of developers working for years.  You would have to be much more specific about what you want in order for YOU to estimate.  None of us know how efficiently you program, so could not give a meaningful estimate on how long it would take you even with a detailed feature list.

Comment: The post is a little ambiguous, but I think he's talking about facebook's "Like" button.  Not recreating facebook.

Comment: @Frank: I belong to the 0.5% of internet-connected people that doesn't use Facebook regularly :-)  I read it as Facebook-like features.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity... long day

Comment: @Eric I read it the same way, at first.  And it's not at all uncommon for people to try to recreate popular web apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really couldn't get much easier.  Throw facebook's js in the header, and drop a `<fb:like>`  tag in.  Or, there's a `<iframe>` based solution that doesn't require a js include.

Examples of both are available via [facebook's code generator](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like).  Basic implementation should take under an hour.  If you go all out, it might take a day at the outside.

Comment: Facebook has made this incredibly easy (perhaps more to their benefit than ours). It took me less than 20 minutes to integrate it into an existing web app (and that included research!).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the Facebook feature where users can 'like' external pages? If so...

I'd recommend having a look at [Add This](http://www.addthis.com/) rather than your own implementation which could take a while to work out - they offer a simple copy and paste javascript snippet that will add Facebook like functionality as well as other social bookmarking options for each of your product pages. They also allow you to track products being bookmarked and track click backs from user bookmarking.

If you mean your own custom feature for your site for users to 'like' products and then highlight them on a feed / homepage, then you'll need to track these 'likes' from users in a database and display them on the relevant page. The amount of time this sort of feature will take to develop really depends how far you want to take it. Obviously Facebook's featureset is massive and I wouldn't imagine you'd want to turn your ecommerce site into too much of a social networking site... hence my guess that you mean something like [Add This](http://www.addthis.com/)?

Comment: Facebook updated the "like" button a month or two ago.  It's now almost as easy to implement as AddThis.  FWIW, we've had AddThis running on a production site for over a year now, and I'm not a big fan.  Their servers were unreliable for a few weeks, and their javascript include blocked rendering of our pages until it timed out.  And their admin/reporting panel didn't work for us at all for months.  Just died with some error.  I was not impressed at all.  Facebook's "like" iframe tag can't cause page rendering to block (since iframes load late), so that's one reason to go that route.